# Incrementing count inside of a generator or other solution

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tkinter

I'm trying to create a 2D list by getting the contents of a bunch of entry widgets but I can't figure out how to create the list.

I tried doing it as a generator by doing

```
hwklist = [[student, entries[i].get()] for student in student_group_list]
```

but for it to work I need to increment `i` to distinguish between the different entry widgets as `entries` is a list of all of them and I can't figure out a way of doing that with a generator.

Below, you can see my solution for getting rid of the generator but now the list is overwritten each time it iterates. I want it to keep appending.

An example of the student group list would be:
`student_group_list = ['BERRY-SMITH Finlay', 'EDWARDS Elizabeth', 'GREGORY Isabella', 'Hendley-Jones Annabel', 'LIS Natalia', 'MANNING Sophie', 'RATCLIFFE George', 'BELLAMY Jacob', 'BOUGHTON Grace', 'GARNETT Archie', 'Maruta Kudzai', 'DAVELIS Alexander', 'DENMAN David', 'JENKIN Jonathan', 'LISTER Thomas', 'CLOWES Edward', 'OGG Holly', 'PUGH Billy']`

If you require to create the field of entry boxes this should give an idea of what I'm using:

```
root = Tk()
entries = []
for f in range (len(student_group_list)
    markentry = Entry(root)
    entries.append(markentry)
    markentry.pack()
    but = Button(root, command = lambda: 2dlist(entries))
    but.pack()
```

My current code:

```
def 2dlist(entries):
    i = 0
    for student in student_group_list:
       hwklist = [[student, entries[i].get()]]
       i = i + 1
    print (hwklist)
```

The output should look something like this:
`[['BERRY-SMITH Finlay', '3'], ['EDWARDS Elizabeth', '5'], ['GREGORY Isabella', '6'], ['Hendley-Jones Annabel', '1'], ['LIS Natalia', '7'], ['MANNING Sophie', '3'], ['RATCLIFFE George', '8'], ['BELLAMY Jacob', '7']]...` and so on depending what the user has inputted into the entry widgets.

Right now I'm just getting `[['PUGH Billy', '7']]` as it's the last item in the list.

Comment: Where does the `3` comes from, in `['BERRY-SMITH Finlay', '3']`?

Comment: have you tried to enumerate the `student_group_list`?

Comment: What you have is not a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator), it's a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `2dlist` function is overwriting `hwklist` with a new, independently created list for every execution of the loop. If you want the function to maintain a running list, then you need to define the variable only once:

```
def 2dlist(entries):
    i = 0
    hwklist = []
    for student in student_group_list:
       hwklist.append([student, entries[i].get()])
       i = i + 1
    print (hwklist)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip` with the comprehension.

```
hwklist = [[student, entry.get()] for student, entry in zip(student_group_list, entries)]
```

Or if you must use slice notation use `enumerate`:

```
hwklist = [[student, entries[i].get()] for i, student in enumerate(student_group_list)]
```